Can Blender Be Used to Create Realistic Jewelry Models for E-Commerce?
I am currently working on a project where I need to create realistic 3D models of vintage jewelry pieces for an online store. These are highly prefered by many customers, so in most of the cases these are attracting sales. We are looking for a software that can create the realistic 3D models of such products.
Image quality is of the prime importance in these businesses, so it should fulfil that need as well. Can I create such models in bulk as well their store have thousands of products and images?
You can check the samples here https://thebackvault.com, so suggest me accordingly.
Need suggestions of those who are using this for e-commerce based purposes.

Hello, of course you can but Blender needs time to be learnt so don't expect to being able to create your models in several weeks

This site works best for focused questions and answers and is not meant for opinions or open ended discussions. You can use the forums at https://blenderartists.org/, there are sections for focused critique and work in progress. To understand how to make better use of this site please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center section, particularly How do I ask a good question? and What types of questions should I avoid asking?.

Blender is capable of photorealism, especially for hard objects like jewelry, yes. You may have some difficulty mimicking light dispersion (i.e. gemstones making rainbows), though there are a few usable tricks such as adding colored refraction shaders with slightly different refraction indices together. This site isn't meant for opinions, so whether or not Blender's capabilities will suit your needs is beyond its scope, however I can point you to examples of advertisements done in Blender, official or fan-made. Hope this helps!
